# Does yum's --enablerepo option only enable a repo for the current command?

Tags: yum, centos

Does yum's `--enablerepo` option only enable a repository for the duration of the current command?

For example if the `enabled` setting in `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo` file is set to `0` (disabled) and I run:

```
yum --enablerepo remi,remi-php55 install php
```

Are the repositories specified (`remi` and `remi-php55`) only enabled for the duration of the `install` command?

Is there a way to persist the `enabled` setting using `yum` instead of editing a `.repo` file directly?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `--enablerepo` option overides the permanent option set in the `.repo` file for only the current command.  `--disablerepo` does the opposite for enabled repos.

If you install (or have installed) the `yum-utils` package then you can use `yum-config-manager` to permanently enable/disable repos without editing the file:

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi
```

will permanently enable the `remi` repo.

```
yum repolist all
```

will list all the repo `id` which you use with the `--enable` or `--disable` option.

Comment: what's the DNF equivalent?

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev - Google found https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Managing_DNF_Repositories.html