# What happens when I enable or disable a repo

Tags: yum

I have seen `yum` used with enableRepo and disableRepo. 
But what happens when I enable a repo say 'apache-tomcat' and what happens if I disable the same repo ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does yum's --enablerepo option only enable a repo for the current command?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153110/does-yums-enablerepo-option-only-enable-a-repo-for-the-current-command)

Answer (score 4):

Actually it is `--enablerepo=repoglob` and `--disablerepo=repoglob`, where *`repoglob`* can stand for a wildcard like `*` or full/part of a repo name. Wildcards should be quoted. This will enable or disable only the respective repos *ad-hoc* for that one command and will not do any changes to files in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`.

For the initial question, if you run `yum` without those options, by default it will use all repos that are defined via `.repo` files in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and which have the key `enabled=1` [and the same for plugins that are enabled].

If you enable a repo `apache-tomcat` you can use the repo with `yum` for that one command by using `--enablerepo=apache-tomcat`. Afterwards the repo will be in its defined state which is configured in `/etc/yum.repos.d/apache-tomcat.repo` (just an example, it's not mandatory to have the filename the same as the repo name).

It would help if you could further refine your question.

Answer (score 0):

enabling or disabling a repo in CentOS is equivalent to zipping or unzipping a repo in /etc/yum.repos.d. for example, a fresh install of CentOS has the CD repo enabled, if you want to disable it, simply gzip the repo and gunzip the other to use them. Don't forget to yum update after you do that.

Comment: Sorry but that is imprecise and partly not correct. If you want to permanently disable a repo, either edit the .repo file or use `yum-config-manager --disable <reponame>` and there is no need to run yum update after you enable or disable a repo, as yum will detect repo changes and will automatically update repository metadata if necessary.